# How to decode mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql

I have saved some information in database with MySQL, now i want to show them, cause it contains some tags like `<div>`, `<p>`, etc. I just want them showed as raw html code, anyone can tell me how? i try to use `html_entity_decode(), but it does not work.

Example:

```
&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;Prénom/Nom : &lt;/b&gt;tantantan tan&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;Pseudonyme : &lt;/b&gt;nickname&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;Résidence principale : &lt;/b&gt;69001 Lyon 1er&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&lt;b&gt;Autre résidence : &lt;/b&gt; Place bellecours 69002 Lyon 2e&lt;/div&gt;
```

====== in fact , i need to do in this way.

```
#using serialize() method
$data = serialize($_SESSION);
$sql = "Insert into sessioninfo `data` values('$data')";
```

and then

```
# I assume you can retrieve the data from database and assign to the following variable
$data = unserialize($row['data']);
```

perfectly resolve my problem. thanks everyone.

Comment: please post an example of the data stored.

Comment: well, i paste the example in the question.

Comment: In fact, the string is re-escaped another time by twig, so my question is how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would recommend not to apply htmlspecialchars when you save the database.
The sanitize should be applied when sending output, if necessary.

Comment: I'm totally agree with your opinion, but i really face a terrible problem is the old database use tables with an id referencing to different tables by different conditions, so i do not wanna to retrieve all these kind of shit in those tables with symfony2 and doctrine. So i try to prepare them and save all together in my new  table and when i need them,i just get it from my table.. I do not need to    modify them so it should work. but if you have anyidea, pls let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an **mysql_real_escape_string** data but **html_specialchars()** encoded data

you can do the reverse with [htmlspecialchars_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Comment: hum, i do not know why, but neither of them works. in fact ,When i store the string , i use : mysql_real_escape_string($userInfo);  
When i get them , i use symfony2 with twig, so the part of view is :
{{ object.userInfo || decoder}} 
i create a twig extension to decode them, i tried what you told me but none of them works.

Comment: @ferdinandfly ignoring symfony, what happens if you just `echo` out the values with `html_entity_decode`?

Answer (score 2):

Try [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
echo html_entity_decode($string);
```